# Random select drop down menu imacros

Tags: drop-down-menu, imacros

I am trying to figure out how to randomized a *drop down menu* in iMacros.

This is the current script.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/es/crear-tu-blog/ ATTR=NAME:domain CONTENT=$activos-blog.net
```

There are like 30 alternative for this *drop down menu*, I want to make it select a random alternative. How can i do this?.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the dropdown menu like this.

This is the current script.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/es/crear-tu-blog/ ATTR=NAME:domain CONTENT=#5
```

In some cases, I saw `%5` so I am not sure is it `%` or `#` before the number. The number 5, in this case, is just an example.

Here is what it says on iMacros.

http://wiki.imacros.net/TAG

Scroll down to where it says dropdown menu.

The next step is to create a random number with use of JavaScript. On the link below, you can get the functions for that purpose.

[Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

After you've mastered that the next step is to implement it in iMacros. You have to use JavaScript scripting.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/es/crear-tu-blog/ ATTR=NAME:domain CONTENT=#{{number}}";


iimSet("number",some_random_number)
iimPlay(macro)
```

Comment: i dont understand javascripting :/, can you help me a lil be more with this.

Comment: Sorry I can't write script for you. I gave you the basic model on how to write script on your own. Find someone to do it for you if you don't know JS.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var randomDomain=Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 1); randomDomain;")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/es/crear-tu-blog/ ATTR=NAME:domain CONTENT=%{{!VAR1}}
```

Where 30 is the number of elements in the drop down menu, and the % indicates we are selecting the option by its value.

For example, I'm expecting the option to be:

```
<option value="12">activos-blog.net</option>
```

If the value is a string, then you should select the option by its index, using #.