# How to add a "random" button that applies to two drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a page with two drop-down menus containing various values.
Now I would like to add a "randomize" button. When clicked, this button would select any of the values at random in both fields. (the values are also copied on a box above each menu).

[Project idea for drop down menus](http://ge.tt/2QfgkxF2/v/0)

So far I've coded the menus and the words display in the boxes above them when the user selects them. But now I'm trying to add a randomise button that would put any of the values in the drop down as selected and of course displayed in the above text box. Ideally, more values in the drop-down menus would be added every once in a while without making the script dysfunctional... and ideally it would all be contained in a HTML file (calling for JQuery or javascript is ok).

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076016/randomize-all-dropdown-select-with-same-class-in-jquery) but it doesn't apply.

I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802295/random-select-drop-down-menu-imacros) but it's not really a feature that the user activates.

Very grateful if anyone can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076016/randomize-all-dropdown-select-with-same-class-in-jquery) you have provided is very close to what you want to do. You just need to:

1. Get a `random` value between `0` and `options.length - 1`.
2. Get `option[random]` and set its `selected` property to `true`.
3. Copy that option's `.innerHTML` or `.value` to the `.innerHTML` or `.value` of the label on top of the dropdowns.

This is all you probably need:

```js
function randomizeSelect(selectId, fieldId) {

    var options = document.getElementById(selectId).children;

    var random = Math.floor(options.length * (Math.random() % 1));

    var option = options[random];
    option.selected = true;
    
    document.getElementById(fieldId).value = option.innerHTML; // You can use .value instead in both places
}

var values = {};

window.onload = function(e) {

    document.onchange = function(e) { // Event Delegation: http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate
        var t = e.target;
        if(t.tagName == "SELECT")
            document.getElementById(t.id.replace("Select","Label")).value = t.children[t.selectedIndex].innerHTML;  
    }

    document.oninput = function(e) {
        var t = e.target;
        if(t.tagName == "INPUT") {
            if(values.hasOwnProperty(t.id))
                var options = values[t.id];
            else
                var options = document.getElementById(t.id.replace("Label","Select")).children;
        
            var currentValue = t.value;
      
            for(i in options) {
                if(options[i].innerHTML == currentValue) { // Can also use .value
                    options[i].selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("randomize").onclick = function(e) {
        randomizeSelect("leftSelect", "leftLabel");
        randomizeSelect("rightSelect", "rightLabel");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="leftLabel" value="Left 1">

<select id="leftSelect">
  <option value="l1" selected>Left 1</option>
  <option value="l2">Left 2</option>
  <option value="l3">Left 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="rightLabel" value="Right 1">

<select id="rightSelect">
  <option value="r1" selected>Right 1</option>
  <option value="r2">Right 2</option>
  <option value="r3">Right 3</option>
</select>

<button id="randomize">RANDOMIZE</button>
```

Comment: This is great! This is the closest I got to what I'm trying to achieve...
I used your code, but it seems that parts of it make it impossible for the user to change the value in the menus by themselves. The script that displays the code in a text box also seems to fight with it?
Here it is:
http://fabulousrice.com/external-file/menu-dan.html

Comment: I have edited the code to always keep the data being displayed in both the `input` and the `select` consistent (even when you type).

Comment: You should also revise your JS code as you have a few errors appearing on the console and take a look at the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffabulousrice.com%2Fexternal-file%2Fmenu-dan.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=HTML5&group=0), as you have a few serious errors in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help... I cleaned up the code using W3C, but it still won't work... Depressing! Thanks for all the help, though, I really appreciate it.
Here's the latest version using your updated suggestions:
http://fabulousrice.com/external-file/menu-dan-4.html

Comment: You should wrap part of the code in a `window.onload` handler to prevent your code from trying to access a DOM element before the DOM is fully loaded. I've updated the code.

Comment: Hey Your version works great. I'll mark that it solved my problem, although Santiago was a close second!

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps
HTML :

```
<select id="s1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var minNumber = 0;
var maxNumber = 3;

function randomNumberFromRange(min,max)
{
    return  Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);


}


$("#s2")[0].selectedIndex = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
$("#s1")[0].selectedIndex = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
```

I create this fiddle for you...
https://jsfiddle.net/s59g8vdp/

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't see the randomise button

Comment: I voted for this instead of mine because it is more similar to what you wanted. Simply add the last two lines as function, and add a button that calls that function and you're done - https://jsfiddle.net/aqpwcoju/1/

Answer (score 0):

This will create random number and click on random div menu:

```
    $(function(){
$(".menu").click(function(){
    alert("you clicked "+$(this).text());
    });
}); 

function doSomthing(){

   var rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
   alert(rand+1);
   var ele = $(".menu").get(rand);
   $(ele).click();

}
```

fiddle example: [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zq3skwmc/)

Or you can use this example to put value in the menu, or wherever you want: [link 2](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hhun2r71/2/)

Comment: The links you have created are interesting, but this is not what I call a "drop-down" menu, since all the values are displayed on top of each other. Also, I want the values to be randomised in the menus and above text boxes, not in a pop-up window. Thanks a lot anyways! It's interesting

Answer (score 0):

just a concept how to make that

```
$('input').on('click',function(){
    var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*$('ul li').length);
    alert($('ul li').eq(randomnum).text());
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmqx4sbz/)

Comment: This is really cool, but the random value appears in a pop-up box. I want the value set in the drop-down menu to be changed. Thanks anyways! Interesting process

Answer (score 0):

Randomize Button added
see... ;) i hope this solve your problem!

https://jsfiddle.net/s59g8vdp/1/

Html :

```
<select id="s1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<a id="randomize" href="#">randomize</a>
```

Javascript :

```
var minNumber = 0;
var maxNumber = 3;

$("#randomize").click(function(){
    $("#s2")[0].selectedIndex = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
$("#s1")[0].selectedIndex = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
});

function randomNumberFromRange(min,max)
{
    return  Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);


}


$("#s2")[0].selectedIndex = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
$("#s1")[0].selectedIndex = randomNumberFromRange(minNumber, maxNumber);
```

Comment: Awesome! I just tried adapting it to my page but I think that it fights with another script that displays the text in boxes... Here's your page suggestions:
http://fabulousrice.com/external-file/menu-santiago.html

Comment: Hey Santiago! Thank you very much. I updated your results onto my test page, but still, no success! I'm having a hard time figuring what's wrong...
http://fabulousrice.com/external-file/menu-santiago-1.html